# Register a feature in Android application

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on developing a React Native feature in my existing Native Android Application. I am using Deeplinking with URL Schema to navigate from React Native feature to existing Screens in Android App.

I want to register my feature inside the application so that application can provide a URL schema that can be used by React Feature package to make callbacks. What is the best way to handle such situation?

**My current package structure:**

```
Package1: AndroidApp
Package2: ReactFeature (responsible for enabling bridging inside the app)
Package3: ReactJS (React Native JS UI and functionality)
```

I am importing the ReactJS in Config of React Feature and importing React Feature in Config of Android App to access React Screens inside Android App.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have an android code base where few new screens are in react native.
I have a controller screen where app gets all deep links, In this controller screen I decide myself what screen should be opened.

```
 <application>
        <activity
            android:name="com.companyname.activities.other.ScreenSelectControllerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="your host"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="your host"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="if any custom scheme to be supported" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

in ScreenSelectControllerActivity

```
public class ScreenSelectControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, this);
        String urlToOpen = getIntent().getData().toString();
        //navigate to appropriate screen 
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can register a react native activity to get all deeplink urls and then open appropriate screens.